# Create a column copying the data from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL and I want to add a column on a table, but it's default value i would like to copy the data from another column, for example:

I have the table test with 2 simple columns:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST

+----+-------------+
| ID | DESCRIPTION |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | test 1      |
|  2 | test 2      |
|  3 | test 3      |
|  4 | test 4      |
+----+-------------+
```

I would like to add a column on the same table, assuming the data from the description, so if I run:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD COLUMN DESCRIPTION2 VARCHAR(20)
```

I would get:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST

+----+-------------+--------------+
| ID | DESCRIPTION | DESCRIPTION2 |
+----+-------------+--------------+
|  1 | test 1      | test 1       |
|  2 | test 2      | test 2       |
|  3 | test 3      | test 3       |
|  4 | test 4      | test 4       |
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

I could easily do this with a simple update after the alter table, but since the table I intend to do this is gigantic, i would rather do it in a single statement for the performance gain, but I don't know if that's possible as i didn't find anything related to this matter on MySQL documentation.

Just to be sure, i tried running:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD COLUMN DESCRIPTION2 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT `DESCRIPTION`
```

but this is a violation of syntax

Is there a better way to do this rather than an update?

Comment: Why two description columns? Why store same data twice?

Comment: In my application, i need to manipulate the value from column 1, but keep it's original value for some validations

Comment: What is your mysql version ? In newer versions, you can look at [Generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Thanks @MadhurBhaiya but my version don't support that. Also, from what i understood, the generated columns will always follow that rule, but in my case, if i updated column1, i can't update value from column2. But thanks for the note, that is a pretty neat thing to know

Answer (score 0):

You can't change table structure and update data in the same statement. You need to use ALTER TABLE and UPDATE separately unless it's a generated column.